# ReactNative adding markers to a map Unexpected token, expected

Tags: google-maps, react-native, maps, react-native-ios

I have a iOS react native app with a map in it and I am trying to get some markers on it but I keep getting the following error

> Unexpected token, expected ...

Anyone knows what is going on here?

This is my constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isFirstLoad: true,
            annotations: [],
            mapRegion: undefined,
            markers: [{
                title: 'Marker1',
                coordinates: {
                    latitude: 3.148561,
                    longitude: 101.652778
                },
            },
            {
                title: 'Marker2',
                coordinates: {
                    latitude: 3.149771,
                    longitude: 101.655449
                },
            }]
        };
    }
```

And my render function:

```
return (
            <MapView
                style={ styles.map }
                onRegionChangeComplete={onRegionChangeComplete}
                region={this.state.mapRegion}
                annotations={this.state.annotations}
                zoomEnabled={true}
                showsUserLocation={true}

                {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                    <MapView.Marker
                        coordinate={marker.coordinates}
                        title={marker.title}
                    />
                ))}
            />
        );
```

It is complaining about this line: `{this.state.markers.map(marker => (`

Any help is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

your error is you are put the tag "MapView.Marker" inside in the "MapView"

your code goes working with this

```js
return (
            <MapView
                style={ styles.map }
                onRegionChangeComplete={onRegionChangeComplete}
                region={this.state.mapRegion}
                annotations={this.state.annotations}
                zoomEnabled={true}
                showsUserLocation={true}               
            >
                {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                    <MapView.Marker
                        coordinate={marker.coordinates}
                        title={marker.title}
                    />
                ))}
              </MapView>

        );
```

Comment: This really helped me to dynamically place a MapMarker dynamically.  BTW, marker.coordinates and marker.title are merely logical names.  We could use something else like marker.geoposition and marker.businessname.  But in all code samples I've seen, I only see marker.coodinates, etc.  Just an FYI.